# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I'm trying to run a test with Node. Here's my directory structure
[image]

[image]
[image]
However, when I run the code, I get the following error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Ben\Documents\tankanarchy\index.html'`
I have looked over my code multiple times and have no idea why I'm getting this error. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is `index.html` not in `C:\Users\Ben\Documents\tankanarchy\static`? If so you should either move it up a level to match the location in your code, or change the code to include the subdirectory `static/ `before `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set an absolute path or specify root. Based on your file structure you can specify root in this manner:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) => {
    response.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'static'});
});
```